# Detect that VSTO tools are installed in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, vsto

How do I detect that Microsoft Office Developer tools are installed in VS?

NOT the VSTO-runtime, but the **package in the Microsoft Visual Studio**.

For example: user can exclude them on Visual Studio installation.
detecting Visual Studio Professional is also not an option - for example, in community edition (detected as PRO) there is no VSTO included.

Answer (score 0):

Nikolay,

You can find the list of installed VS add-ons listed on the About dialog. I believe that all these entries are stored in the windows registry somewhere. Try using the **ProcessMonitor** for checking what records are added or changed when you install VSTO or any other add-ons.

UPDATE: You can use the IVsShell ingterface which provides the GetProperty method for that. See [HOWTO: Detect installed Visual Studio editions, packages or service packs](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi Eugene, the points is that VSTO, unlike regular packages cannot be installed/uninstalled using Tools -> Extensions (and probably because of that is not listed under "packages" registry key). It looks like it's installed as a separate product by VS setup. Therefore I ask, actually.. Maybe it can be detected by product id? Where could I get that id then (and may it different for different versions of VSTO)? It would be nice to get some link to docs in that direction (if there are any).

Comment: You can use the IVsShell ingterface which provides the GetProperty method. See [HOWTO: Detect installed Visual Studio editions, packages or service packs](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx) for more information.